# Как установить rasa в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть гайд как установить rasa через conda, но мне нужно в PyCharm. По гайду на официальном сайте не получатся.

Comment: Устанавливаете через conda, потом подцепляете интерпретатор, который идет с anaconda, как интерпретатор проекта.

Comment: устанавливаю через miniconda, всё по официальному гайду, но при установке ошибка Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ... error

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать виртуальную среду в терминале PyCharm.

```
python3 -m venv ./venv
```

После обновить библиотеку pip, если оно нужно и скачиваете rasa в виртуальной среде:

```
pip install rasa
```

Убедитесь, что версии python и rasa сходятся. Rasa поддерживает версии с 3.6 по 3.8 если я не ошибаюсь

Answer (score 0):

rasa работает с python 3.7-3.8 Скачайте python 3.7.9 и пропишите

```
py -3.7 -m venv .\venv
py -3.7 -m pip install - U pip
py -3.7 -m pip install rasa
py -3.7 -m rasa init
```